# How to retrieve data from XML in Spring Integration

Tags: java, xml, spring-integration

I have link

http://www.somelink.com

When I send it with GET Method, I've got XML in view like this

```
<Value>
  <Id>41</Id>
  <Date>2017-08-16</Date>
  <Role>Customer</Role>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
  <Counterparties>
    <Counterparty><Id>183</Id>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <FullName>dddd</FullName>
    <Contacts>
      <Contact>
        <Type>Mail</Type>
        <Value>email.com</Value>
      </Сontact>
      <Goods>
        <Good>
          <Id>AxojoXSQgN0MZTRX87SJ11</Id>
          <CatalogId>1c_catalog-bd72d8f9-55bc-11d9-848a-00112f43529a</CatalogId>
          <Name>*Good name</Name>
          <Price>340.0000</Price>
          <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
          <Sum>340</Sum>
          <Status>[N]New State (И-М)</Status>
          ...
</Value>
```

So I need transform this xml to object using Spring Integration, but I don't need retrieve all data, just some as Good Name, Counterparty Name and Price with Quantity and transform this into DTO. How to do it best? With JSON it is much easier, but I don't have JSON

Comment: If you need to transform xml to Pojo, you don't need spring, you can use `Jaxb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you still can use `<unmarshaller-transformer>`, but I'm not sure how it would be possible to avoid nested structure. Although the `<int-xml:xpath-transformer>` should help you to extract the nested `<Good>` tag and then send the result to the  `<unmarshaller-transformer>`.

On the other hand you can just use `Content Enricher` component for simple POJO and call `#xpath()` SpEL function for properties to extract an appropriate value from that XML.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher